# Listview checkbox becomes unselected when scroll down

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have created a custom listview with a checkbox and two line of text. I want to change the checkbox state when I click on the list item (this means that if I click any part of the list item checkbox or text, checkbox will change state).
To achieve this I have added this in the custom_list_row xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

and in the java class I did these:

```
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final CheckBox checkBox;
            checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);


            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

This works fine. But the only problem is that when I select some items and scroll down-->the go back to the selected items-->the selected items becomes unselected.

I did not do anything with setOnCheckedChangeListener

What went wrong? Any suggestion to solve this problem will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you need to maintain boolean array for that

Comment: did you mean I have to create an array which will save the state of all checkbox?

Comment: yes ,,but try to use recyclerview

Comment: It's nothing to do with view. Just create an ArrayList for the state of all checkboxes. Then add their values to the list in listview's click. After use that list in your adapter like checkBox.setChecked(arrayList.get(position));

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you need to use recyclerview

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private Toolbar toolbar;

 private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
 private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

 private List<Student> studentList;

 private Button btnSelection;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  btnSelection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

  studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

  for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
   Student st = new Student("Student " + i, "androidstudent" + i
     + "@gmail.com", false);

   studentList.add(st);
  }

  if (toolbar != null) {
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Android Students");

  }

  mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

  // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
  // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
  mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

  // use a linear layout manager
  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

  // create an Object for Adapter
  mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(studentList);

  // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

  btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    String data = "";
    List<Student> stList = ((CardViewDataAdapter) mAdapter)
      .getStudentist();

    for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
     Student singleStudent = stList.get(i);
     if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {

      data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.getName().toString();
      /*
       * Toast.makeText( CardViewActivity.this, " " +
       * singleStudent.getName() + " " +
       * singleStudent.getEmailId() + " " +
       * singleStudent.isSelected(),
       * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       */
     }

    }

    Toast.makeText(CardViewActivity.this,
      "Selected Students: \n" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
   }
  });

 }

}
```

For more see http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

**OR**

If you want to use listview try this way

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Context context;
    private List<Modelclass> listData;

    public CustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, List<Modelclass> listData) {
        context = mainActivity;
        this.listData = listData;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poojaselection, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaname);
            holder.checks = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojacheck);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checks.setFocusable(false);

        if (listData.get(position).isselected) {
            holder.checks.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checks.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {

                if (checkMaxLimit()) {

                    if (listData.get(position).isselected && b) {
                        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;

                    } else {
                        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Max limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (b) {
                        listData.get(position).isselected = true;
                    } else {
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).getLISTING_NAME());
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean checkMaxLimit() {
        int countermax = 0;
        for(Modelclass item : listData){
            if(item.isselected){
                countermax++;
            }
        }
        return countermax >= 5;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        public CheckBox checks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make change while checkbox is select/unselect

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final CheckBox checkBox;
            checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);


            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                checkBox.setChecked(false);

                    // Reset the checkbox in array list/Bean  like 

                    list.set(); // set new value of list 

                    adapter.notifyChange();

            }
            else {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);

                 // Reset the checkbox in array list/Bean  like 

                    list.set(); // set new value of list 

                    adapter.notifyChange();
            }
        }
    });
```

This change solve this issue of mine.